# MultipartHttpServletRequest.getParts() return partial data (Image or gif content is null/empty)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I have a Spring Application with REST API to accept MMS and the API structure is like

```
public ResponseEntity<String> forwardMMS(@RequestParam(name = "recipients") @NotBlank String recipients,
                                             @RequestParam(name = "sender") @NotBlank String sender,
                                             @RequestParam(name = "subject", required = false) String subject,
                                             @RequestHeader(name = "X-Transaction-ID", required = false) String uuidFromHeader,
                                             MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartHttpServletRequest)
```

I have issues when trying to retrieve the parts from the multipartHttpServletRequest for Image or gif files.

below is the code:

```
private List<Part> getMmsContentParts(MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartHttpServletRequest) {
        List<Part> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for (Part part : multipartHttpServletRequest.getParts()) {
                if (part.getName().equals("mmsContent")) {
                    attachments.add(part);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error getting Parts", e);
        }
        logContentToDebug(attachments);
        return attachments;
    }

    private void logContentToDebug(List<Part> attachments) {
        for (Part part : attachments) {
            String contentType = part.getContentType();
            LOGGER.debug("File contentType : {} and its content size is : {}", contentType, part.getSize());
        }
    }
```

Logs from My code for the above code

1. For a smil and image file

```
"message":"File contentType : application/smil;charset=UTF-8 and its content size is : 301"
"message":"File contentType : image/jpeg; name=709055746.jpg and its content size is : 0"
```

2. For a smil and video file in 3gp format

```
"message":"File contentType : application/smil;charset=UTF-8 and its content size is : 302"
"message":"File contentType : video/3gpp; name=709048525.3gp and its content size is : 1045"
```

I logged the request body using the Filter to check if I'm actually receiving the image file or not. In request body the image file content in base64 format is present.

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        String requestBody = IOUtils.toString(httpRequest.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        LOGGER.info("Request Body {}: ", requestBody);
    }
```

request body log for both image and Video requests

1. Request body with Image

```
Request Body: 
------=_Part_22_1815075090.1687446854525
Content-Type: application/smil;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: 0.smil
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=mmsContent

<smil>
<head>
<layout>
 <root-layout/>
<region id="Text" top="70%" left="0%" height="30%" width="100%" fit="scroll"/>
<region id="Image" top="0%" left="0%" height="70%" width="100%" fit="meet"/>
</layout>
</head>
<body>
<par dur="10s">
<img src="709055746.jpg" region="Image"/>
</par>
</body>
</smil>

------=_Part_22_1815075090.1687446854525
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=709055746.jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: 0
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=709055746.jpg; name=mmsContent
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==
------=_Part_22_1815075090.1687446854525
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipients"

1234
------=_Part_22_1815075090.1687446854525
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sender"

45678
------=_Part_22_1815075090.1687446854525--
```

2. request body with video file

```
Request Body: 
------=_Part_18_1310706778.1687446631068
Content-Type: application/smil;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: 0.smil
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=mmsContent

<smil>
<head>
<layout>
 <root-layout/>
<region id="Text" top="70%" left="0%" height="30%" width="100%" fit="scroll"/>
<region id="Image" top="0%" left="0%" height="70%" width="100%" fit="meet"/>
</layout>
</head>
<body>
<par dur="2s">
<video src="709048525.3gp" region="Image"/>
<text src="text_1.txt" region="Text"/>
</par>
</body>
</smil>

------=_Part_18_1310706778.1687446631068
Content-Type: video/3gpp; name=709048525.3gp
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: 0
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=709048525.3gp; name=mmsContent

AAAAHGZ0eXAzZ3A1AAABAGlzb20zZ3A1M2dwNAAABPRtb292AAAAbG12aGQAAAAA4LoU5eC6FOYA
xxxxxx
CgM7Gda2z+LyUU7wX7IzwAAAhB/62/AAAIgetkjGM1sWCTB8QEkfYwG8AACMHp6YF8HxADUAJ4oH
J1fB6f9ED0gKmCekBLR4XrAtSstTkaHg9oCCahYPiAg9n/wAAJAelxcD3f5pfBfAnAPqfF4kgwQO
XD8GADgDviUJPy4GBCoPx6DBA0HSoRy4f+L8oiqWzdeJYQwg+H4KDyoSADL5R/QDlV3gKPw7t/85
UKhJAM9VXgYANCEEMfj8D/gUECCEPwIQIYKS/VFxcxWAcH9pggKy8S/QGB9QQAYAPBQl0ioeiWP1
YlF/wUymQf+9/Izi2kr+nIn5TEEhbQjcMEWNKuH7Rsw3oXN4CsAAAJQexhZay0Fmly0yUNnuhhbz
nAAAmB//AACcH9rJvgAAoB/1NzuAAAA=
------=_Part_18_1310706778.1687446631068
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipients"

1234
------=_Part_18_1310706778.1687446631068
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sender"

45678
------=_Part_18_1310706778.1687446631068--
```

the application properties for multipart handling is

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

I'm out of ideas of what might be the exact problem, can you please help me in solving the issue.

Many thanks in advance.

PS: the API works well for txt files.

**UPDATE :**
I added the below code to print the content of file parts received.

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        List<Part> fileParts = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Part part : httpRequest.getParts()) {
            if (part.getName().equals("mmsContent")) {
                fileParts.add(part);
            }
        }

        for (Part part : fileParts) {
            String contentType = part.getContentType();

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line);
                }
                LOGGER.info("File contentType : {} and its content is : {}", contentType, content);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error getting Parts content", e);
            }
        }
```

[image: Log]

Comment: You may try to specify the character encoding explicitly for the start:
`spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8`;
`spring.http.encoding.force=true`

Comment: @yahorbarkouski after adding the UTF-8 encoding property, the issue still exists.
the image part is empty

Comment: Could be the image file is corrupted, Did you try a png and see the result

Comment: For example you can use this https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter to paste the encoded 64 base content to convert into image file. So the base64 should be valid when you log it

Comment: @Youans I was able to decode the base64 encoded image file present in request body. So the image is not corrupted. But for some reason the content is not coming in the Part.